# wso2 get tenantId of user from RemoteUserStoreManagerService getTenantIdOfUser soap

Tags: soap, wso2, soapui, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to get tenantId of the user with username using RemoteUserStoreManagerService service of Wso2. However I am getting Access denied error.

> Unauthorized attempt to execute super tenant operation by tenant
>   domain - carbon.super tenant id - -1234

in the console. I have passed super tenant admin details for authorization. From the code i could see that UserStoreException is thrown where it checks for super tenant id against 0. But my super tenant id is -1234. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As i know, getTenantIdofUser is a depreciated in WSO2 and it will not work properly. Theoretically, you can not retrieve the tenant id by providing the username. Because username is unique across tenants. There can be same username in two different tenant. As you mentioned, there is some issue in the code as well. Super tenant id must be -1234. However fixing this issue, would not provide successful response from the getTenantIdofUser as it is already depreciated.